# How to execute different methods of a class using thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I have 5 classes in my java swing application as follows:

```
SendEmail.java
StudentRegister.java
StudentLogin.java
TeacherRegister.java
TeacherLogin.java
```

Structure of SendEmail.java is as follows:

```
    class sendEmail extends Thread
{
  public void studentMail(){}
  public void teacherMail(){}
}
```

What i want is after successful registration of student from StudentRegister.java i want to direct student to StudentLogin.java also at the same time i want to send student confirmation mail which will be send by studentMail() method of SendEmail.java class.
Same thing i wanna do with Teacher, but this time the method which will send the mail is different i.e. teacherMail().
Here I cannot have one common method run() which can start the execution of thread. How can i execute different methods of class on execution of thread.

Comment: `Thread t = new Thread(() -> { call to studentMail(); });` and then another with a call to `teacherMail`. However, I think you have some bigger organizational issues you should check into. Like should `sendEmail` really (really really) be extending `Thread`? And could you use one notification method with a flag ie `doMail(boolean isStudent)`?

Comment: @Andrew - would not method1() and method2() execute consecutively in such case?

Comment: CollinD, Thank you for your advice. The idea of using notification method may be can do the work. I'll try it!!

Comment: Don't `extends Thread`, but if you do, you need to implement `run()` method.

Comment: This is a bad idea.  You sound like a new programmer who just learned about Threads and is dying to try them out.  Don't.  The tell is your design: sending email is not different for student and teacher.  I'd have a single method that could adjust content based on recipient types.  You should not be dealing with raw Java 1.0 Thread; you should be thinking about the Executor classes in java.util.concurrency package.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a a lot of ways to solve this problem. One that would be pretty easy to implement would be to use a shared interface and code against that instead of your implementation.

```
interface EmailSender {
    void doMail();
}
```

And then just create a couple of implementations

```
class TeacherEmailSender implements EmailSender {
    public void doMail() { /* implementation */}
}
class StudentEmailSender implements EmailSender {
    public void doMail() { /* implementation */}
}
```

Then you could just do something like this and then set its actual implementation as appropriate.

```
EmailSender emailSender;
if (thisIsaStudentRegistration) {
    emailSender = new StudentEmailSender();
} else {
    emailSender = new TeacherEmailSender();
}
new Thread(() -> { emailSender.doMail(); }).run();
```

There are a lot of options here really. Depending upon how generic your notifications need to be, it may be appropriate to create an `enum` of notification types, and then register different handlers for those in a registry class.

If there is a lot of shared functionality between the student and teacher email sending classes, you could probably benefit from a shared partial implementation (`extend` some `abstract` base class).

This is all sort of predicated upon my assumption that this is a class assignment that requires the use of threads. If not, consider skipping the concurrency as mentioned by duffymo.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a single class to send email.  It would not care about student or teacher; to, from, subject, and content would be the only things that mattered.

I'd pass in those values, generating the content differently for `Teacher` and `Student`.

I wouldn't worry about concurrency until I knew I had a performance issue.  You'll be smart to code it simply, get it working, profile the performance, and then change to make performance acceptable.